# Why is my function in r creating num(0) and NULL output?

Tags: r, function

I am trying to make a function in r that creates a matrix of antibiotics against the fraction of which Klebsiella Pneumoniae is 'Resistant','Susceptible', or 'Intermediate' to. However the function I'm currently using:

```
Klebsiella.pneumoniae.rs.mat1 <-         
tapply(Klebsiella.pneumoniae.rs$resistant_phenotype, INDEX = 
list(Klebsiella.pneumoniae.rs$antibiotic), FUN =  function(x)
{
fracR = sum(x=='Resistant')/(nrow(x))

fracS = sum(x=='Susceptible')/(nrow(x))

fracI = sum(x=='Intermediate')/(nrow(x))

return(c(fracR, fracS, fracI))
})
```

is outputting:

```
amikacin                      Numeric,0
ampicillin                    Numeric,0
ampicillin/sulbactam          Numeric,0
aztreonam                     Numeric,0
cefazolin                     Numeric,0
cefepime                      Numeric,0
cefotaxime                    Numeric,0
cefoxitin                     Numeric,0
ceftazidime                   Numeric,0
ceftriaxone                   Numeric,0
cefuroxime                    NULL     
cephalothin                   Numeric,0
....
```

Any idea what is going on here? (the original data is a column of antibiotic names, and a column of resistant phenotypes, and some other columns)

Thanks!

Comment: is your data numeric ? share the data that you are applying this function  on.

Answer (score 1):

Use `length` instead of `nrow`. Or even better, just use `mean`. `nrow` returns the number of rows and there are no rows in a vector.

```
sum(iris$Species == "setosa") / nrow(iris$Species)
#numeric(0)

nrow(iris$Species)
#NULL

length(iris$Species)
#[1] 150

sum(iris$Species == "setosa") / length(iris$Species)
#[1] 0.3333333

mean(iris$Species == "setosa") 
#[1] 0.3333333
```